# in ReactJS fow to place custom Linkedin Follow company button

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

LinkedIn generates this custom html code for follow company button

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="privateID" data-counter="right"></script>
```

but i would like use their script with my custom Icon component how to do that ?
i check for docs but didn't find anything.

Comment: It seems unusual that you would need to load a whole javascript file just for a button. Most likely you're going to need to reverse engineer the link that they're generating and add it to your own button in React.

Comment: Before you will do anything with linkedin follow company script, make sure that it is working. I was trying to follow and it only opens blank page.

Comment: @IcetI notice that some browsers are doesn't support that if you try with the latest version of Firefox. it opens a blank page, then when a promise resolves it redirects to some notification page.

Comment: They seem to have fixed their button. It follow/unfollows the Page and takes you to the Page on a new tab. If you don't want to include the whole JS file, you can include the following link as an iFrame: https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id=18055982&counter=bottom (replace id & counter with the desired values)